# Maven set default value to propertie if environment value is not set , overwrite the default value if set

Tags: maven, variables, environment-variables, maven-3

i have a simple variable in pom.xml that works great when the environment variable is set in the running env
for example :

```
<properties>
        <my_var>XXXXX</my_var>      
        <image.name>${my_var}</image.name>
</properties>
```

this is working great is no my_var defined in the running env,
but when I ser

```
export my_var=YYYYYY
```

and run maven i still getting the XXXXX value in image.name
i need the environment variable overwrite the default value if defined

Answer (score 0):

You could use maven profiles in your pom.xml like this example:

```
<properties>
    <my_var>XXXXX</my_var>      
    <image.name>${my_var}</image.name>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Y</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
               <name>envVarName</name>
               <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
           <my_var>YYYYY</my_var>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And you can do activation of each one depends on the value of the environment variable. Therefore, if you run:

`mvn clean package -DenvVarName=true` (You can run `mvn clean package -PY` too)

Only the match profile is activated and property my_var is overwrote.